# Splitting strings in Java

Tags: java, strings

I wrote a function which takes in input a list of strings that is splitted by comma. Then each generated string is trimmed.

Example:

```
INPUT:    [[Cat, Dog, Snake]]
OUTPUT:   Cat Dog Snake
```

In particular, I'm interested in removing parenthesis and commas.
This is the code I wrote, but I think it is awful and not so efficient because I use so many String and LinkedList variables.

```
private List<String> splitListOfString(LinkedList<String> list)
{
String mylist = list.toString(); //is made by parenthesis, I do not want
mylist = mylist.substring(2);  //delete the first 2
mylist = mylist.substring(0, mylist.length() - 2); //delete the last 2
List<String> thelist = Arrays.asList(mylist.split(","));
List<String> thelist2 = new LinkedList<String>();
for (String string : thelist) {
    thelist2.add(string.trim());
}
    return thelist2;
}
```

The line of code involving the trim function is compulsory to avoid something like " string", that is undesirable. But I do not think that this is the best way to write this code.
How would you improve this?

Comment: I am confused by your requirements. Could you maybe edit your question to add a few examples (preferrably as Java code test cases) that show the expected behavior of your function?

Comment: Am I wrong or can this method be replaced by `return list` ???

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure how you got the original list-within-a-list input, but have you looked into [Java Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)? Here's a [tutorial](http://winterbe.com/posts/2014/07/31/java8-stream-tutorial-examples/) that may help.

It looks like you're taking in a LinkedList, turning it into a string to manually delete the [[ and ]], splitting on comma, then adding each item to a new list.

Why not do something like the following:

```
private static List<String> splitListOfString(LinkedList<String> list) { 
    List<String> myList = new LinkedList<>();
    list.stream().forEach(item -> myList.add(item));
    return myList;
}
```

In the above code, you're leaving the elements in the list (instead of converting to string), retrieving each item, then adding to your output list. It may need to be modified slightly to match your input.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Nice first answer you got here. To make it even better: `list.stream().collect(Collectors.toList())`. And to make it match the original code:  `list.stream().map(String::trim).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Answer (score 3):

---

### Formatting

Your overall code formatting leaves to be desired. Please use consistent blocks and whitespace.

It helps hugely in readability. Most IDEs will do it automatically for you whenever the file is saved. Pay attention to how I *used* whitespaces to convey meaning in my last code snippet.

---

### Naming

Here are your variables:

```
list    
myList
theList
theList2
```

Not terribly clear, is it?

Some of them are `Lists`, some are `Strings`. This is further confusing. Also what does each one do? It is really not obvious because their naming does not tell us.

You should call them with meaningful names like:

```
list      --> inputList
myList    --> comaSeparatedElement
theList   --> workingList
theList2  --> resultList
```

Naming things correctly is hugely important:

- For you: to keep your algo and your concept under control. Naming gives control.
- For your readers: to read your mind, because you're not there to tell them, and you've forgotten about the code and moved on with your life.

---

### Try to review your requirements

Apparently the animals are in a `String`, that `String` is formatted as if it was a `animalList.toString()`, and the `String` is also, itself, in a `List`.

Using a `String` is a very bad choice to communicate a list of animals. Can you change it? If so, please do so. Also, have you thought about what happens if the input contains two String like :

```
["[Cat, Dog]", "[Snake, Scorpion]"]
```

Then do all elements need to go into the same output List?

---

### Don't over-constrain your inputs

What if I had an `ArrayList` I wanted to submit? I can't use your function, it *requires* a `LinkedList`. What if I had a `List<String>`,and didn't even know its implementation? Sure, I can copy it all to a `LinkedList`, but its such a waste...

You're not even using the knowledge of your specific List type! `LinkedList` has `getFirst()`, `getLast()`, a `spliterator` etc. But you're not using that. You're only `toString`ing it. So you can open up your method, remove the constraint, and have this signature:

```
private List<String> splitListOfString(List<String> list);
```

---

### Keep the data in its original format

The first thing you did is `list.toString()`. This is messing up the input, which was a nice, practical, `List`. What if the author of LinkedList decided to change the format of its `toString()` method? Or if the `LinkedList` you got was actually subclassed by someone who modified the `toString()` method? Keep the data in its original format.

Browse the content using built-in foreach iteration:

```
for(String comaSeparatedElement: inputList){
    // Dosomething with that comaSeparatedElement 
}
```

---

### Substring in one shot

You used substring, which is nice and efficient.

You should have read about the *other* substring method, the one with start and end arguments:

```
comaSeparatedElement = comaSeparatedElement.substring(1, comaSeparatedElement.length() - 1); //delete the 1st and last characters(those are the '[' and the ']'
```

---

### Unleash Java 8

As @ErikaBurdon noted, the remaining 4 lines of code can be advantageously replaced by some concise, and powerful [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) calls.

I can propose a full-strem solution, even though here it looks a bit contrived:

- `Stream`ing the input `List`
- Using flatMap to collect in a single Stream all the pieces of each element, because each coma-separated element is:

  - `substring`ed to remove the leading '[' and trailing ']'
  - `split` at every ',' to make an array of String pieces
  - That array is Streamed (using the [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) utility class)
  - Each element of the sub-stream is `trim`med using map
- Collecting the trimmed Strings in a List

Here you go:

```
private List<String> splitListOfString(List<String> list) {
    return inputList.stream()                // Stream the input
             .flatMap(                       // collect al pieces in a single list
                  comaSeparatedList -> Arrays.stream(comaSeparatedList.substring(1, comaSeparatedList.length() - 1)
                               .split(","))) // Split each string in pieces here
             .map(String::trim)              // Trim each piece
             .collect(Collectors.toList());  // Collect in a single list
}
```